# PrimeFaces p:commandButton not draggable

Tags: primefaces, xhtml, jsf-2.2

This is my XHTML snippet:

```
<h:form><p:separator/><p:panel header="Attachments" toggleable="true" disabled="false" readonly="false" rendered="true">
    <c:forEach id="availableAttachments" items="#{userCRBean.user.attachments}" var="attachment" varStatus="status">
        <p:commandButton ajax="false" disabled="false" id="attachmentButton" readonly="false" rendered="true" value="#{attachment.fileName}">
            <p:fileDownload value="#{userCRBean.handleFileDownload(attachment)}"/>
        </p:commandButton>
    </c:forEach>
    <p:draggable revert="true" for="attachmentButton" disabled="false" readonly="false" rendered="true"/>
    <p:droppable activeStyleClass="ui-state-highlight" tolerance="touch" for="fileUpload" disabled="false" readonly="false" rendered="true">
        <p:ajax listener="#{userCRBean.handleFileDelete(attachment)}" update="" disabled="false" readonly="false" rendered="true"/>
    </p:droppable>
    <p:fileUpload dragDropSupport="true" fileUploadListener="#{userCRBean.handleFileUpload}" id="fileUpload" mode="advanced" sizeLimit="1000000" update="@form"/>
</p:panel></h:form>
```

I would like to have the p:commandButtons generated by the c:forEach draggable, but they don't move at all. Any ideas, what I'm doing wrong here?

PrimeFaces 5.2

Comment: c:forEach is a facelet tag. It doesn't have an `id` attribute. On each iteration it creates new JSF component instances for it's children tags. So you're creating n commandButtons with the same id `attachmentButton`. Append varStatus' value to the button's id to make it unique. Or use ui:repeat, which creates a single instance of its JSF components children, and iterates only their state.

Comment: But in the p:draggable attribute I have to specify the "id" of what needs to be draggable. This wouldn't work anymore if the different buttons would have unique ids. Actually I want them to have the same id.

Comment: Replaced the c:forEach with ui:repeat, now I'm getting a NullPointerException in the DraggableRenderer:

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.primefaces.component.dnd.DraggableRenderer.encodeEnd(DraggableRenderer.java:41)
 at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:919)
 at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:88)
 at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:71)
 at org.primefaces.component.panel.PanelRenderer.encodeContent(PanelRenderer.java:206)

Comment: You probably need to move p:draggable inside iteration too and, if using c:forEach, set  `for` to take varStatus into account too.

Comment: Did it, still not draggable. The generated HTML button has the following class attributes: <button type="submit" onclick="" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" name="j_idt27:attachmentButton0" id="j_idt27:attachmentButton0" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Chrysanthemum.jpg</span></button>